# Deployment of Angular with Spring Boot application in Tomcat

Tags: deployment

Angular Application with Spring Boot works fine in embedded Tomcat server, but the backend part is not working when deployed in a dedicated Tomcat server.  I have done the following to deploy the application.  First deployed the Spring Boot application

1. War packaging is given in the pom.xml
2. Dependency for dedicated Tomcat is provided
3. main class extends SpringBootServletInitializer
4. from the command line run mvn clean install
5. then deployed the war file in Tomcat
   In Angular application
6. run the ng build command -> ng build --base-href=/myApp/
7. then created a folder named myApp in the webapps folder
8. then copied all the contents of the dist folder to myApp folder
9. tried to access the app from the dedicated tomcat server.  Front end part is displayed, but not the back end part.  Can somebody help?

Back end part is not working